# What is the name of this style?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I would like to if the style as highlighted in below 3 images are defined in static resources. if yes what is its name ?

e.g StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle is a StaticResource and can be usedto set Style.

Image 1
[image]

Image 2
[image]

Image 3
[image]

Comment: Is it here? http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/pre-defined-system-styles-and

Comment: OK..that looks good..can you confirm which one is the style from that link used to set list shown in image 2 (Internet Explorer item) ?